# How to show last available data in google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have two columns(sales and calendar day) along with many columns. I just need to show the sales of the last available calendar day in a score card.

Challenge here is I don't know what is last available calendar day. In the below example I would need 120 to be displayed in score card.

In my current setup it always displays, aggregated values which is 270

For example,

Date       Sales  Region        City 
25/07/2021 150     Australia    Canberra
27/07/2021 120     Australia    Canberra

can you folks please guide me on how to get value 120 in data studio without using scorecard filter

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filter for a score card would not work, because the last date is not know.

The only workaround is to use a table and order descending by date and  limit the `Rows per Page` to one.

[image]

It would look like that, if the style of the table is adjusted:

[image]

The date column could be put to minimum width and be hidden by a rectangle with the background color. Or do not show the header of the table and add a contional formating to make the color of the text in the date column the color of the background. Another way is to remove the date column and keep the date only in the sort field.

***A more complex way is to create a blend:***
Please create a new blend and include your data source twice. On the left one, please only have the date column in the metrics and use as aggregation `max`. Then do a left join with that field and the date column of the table on the right. Please include all needed dimensions and metrics.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but in the table I would have date dimension, otherwise sales would be aggregated. How to get rid of the date column in table chart

Comment: @Robert I updated my answer: you have to hide the date column: put a box over it :-)

Comment: And is there a way to apply the "last available date" filter to other elements like charts of groups of charts?